# Link Javascript and JQuery Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I know this problem is pretty common at this moment and many people are asking the same question but for know I can't find any good solutions.

I wonder how i should implantate my scripts to wordpress?

This how far I have come:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_register_script("contact-form", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/contact-form.js");
    wp_enqueue_script("contact-form");
    wp_register_script("form", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/form.js");
    wp_enqueue_script("form");
    wp_register_script("validate", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/validate.js");
    wp_enqueue_script("validate");
    wp_register_script("answercheck", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/contact/answercheck.js");
    wp_enqueue_script("answercheck");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created a function `my_scripts_method()` and did you call it anywhere? Hooked it to something?

Try with

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method()');
```

Also you can enqueue your scripts directly. So your

```
wp_register_script("contact-form", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/contact-form.js");
wp_enqueue_script("contact-form");
```

Will be

```
wp_enqueue_script("contact-form", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/contact-form.js");
```

If you have no dependencies. Also I'd use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of your `get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory")`.

[get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

**EDIT**

Try putting in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('contact-form', get_template_directory_uri().'/form/contact-form.js','','', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('form', get_template_directory_uri().'/form/form.js','','', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('validate', get_template_directory_uri().'/form/validate.js','','', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('answercheck', get_template_directory_uri().'/contact/answercheck.js','','', true);
}
```

Alternatively you can put `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`, if it doesn't work. But it should (unless you don't have anything in the `/form` and `/contact` folders).

Comment: This is what I got in my source code now. <script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme/form/contact-form.js?ver=4.2.4'></script>

Comment: It still doesn't work unfortunately. This how I did in my funtions.php: add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method()');


wp_enqueue_script("contact-form", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/contact-form.js");
wp_enqueue_script("form", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/form.js");
wp_enqueue_script("validate", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/validate.js");
wp_enqueue_script("answercheck", get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . "/form/answercheck.js");

Comment: See my edit, when you inspect the frontend, you should be able to see those scripts loaded in the inspector in the `Sources` tab. Or you should see some kind of an error.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I can see that the script are linked in the source but still the java functions doesn't work.

Comment: If you can see them, then your problem is solved ;) You only asked how to put them in wordpress. Try putting the jquery dependancy on each one like this `wp_enqueue_script('answercheck', get_template_directory_uri().'/contact/answercheck.js',array('jquery'),'', true);`

Comment: I understand that ;) But the problem is that the form which the javascript are for is not working in Wordpress but it works outside Wordpress.

Comment: By in and out you mean, on your HTML page it works, and when you create site with Wordpress it doesn't work, or do you mean front-end and back-end of Wordpress?

Comment: Exactly, my contact form works on a regular html or php page but not inside Wordpress. I also tried to put a smaller java code and link it and that did work so I am really frustrated right now...

Comment: If you want the js files to be visible in the back-end hook it to `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');`